# User authentication and user related content using java jax-rs and angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey-2.0

I am trying to get a grasp on how to create a web application using REST (jersey) on the server side, and angularJS on the client, where a user can register/sign in in a secured fashion.
Once a user is signed in, I want to show user related content (his profile).

There are a few questions on this topic but are focused on specific aspects rather then a complete example, so there are few things I'm still missing.

to be more specific:

How do I use HttpServletRequest.login? the documentation specifies "Validate the provided username and password in the password validation realm used by the web container login mechanism configured for the ServletContext"
How do I specify a login mechanism?

Once a user is signed in, how can i display his profile?

Also, an example of such web application would be wonderful.

Comment: Maybe you should break this question down into smaller, specific questions.  As it is, this feels like, "Can you tell me how to write this feature?"

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sorry if the question is too general. as specified in my question, I'm not sure how to utilize the HttpServletRequest.login method. How can i configure it so that the user credentials would be validated against a mysql DB? and secondly, assuming the user is already logged in, how do i use the session to get the relevant data? I can create a REST resource that  will return a user profile object and use angular to display it, what I'm trying to understand is how to use the current session as an identifier for which object to retreive.

Comment: OK that's two questions.  Why not ask them as two questions?  I've never used or heard about `login` so I can't help you directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful for you to take a look at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com). In your backend, you can use the [Stormpath Java SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java) to easily delegate all your user-management needs. Since you are specifically interested in the login functionality, this is the way you would do it with Stormpath:

There are three options here...

1. You can completely delegate the login/register functionality to Stormpath via its [IDSite](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/)
2. You can also delegate it to our [Servlet Plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html)
3. You want to develop your own login

If you decide to go with option 3:

1. Your front end will display the login form (BWT, Stormpath also supports Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Github login)
2. When the user presses the login button, your front end will send the credentials securely to your backend-end thorough its REST API.
3. Your backend will then try to authenticate the user against the Stormpath Backend:

   ```
   /** This code will throw an Exception if the authentication fails */
   public void postOAuthToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       //Getting the authentication result
       AccessTokenResult result = (AccessTokenResult) application.authenticateApiRequest(request);

       //Here you can get all the user data stored in Stormpath
       Account account = accessTokenResult.getAccount();

       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
       response.setContentType("application/json");

       //Here you can also return some of the user data to your front-end in the response
       JSONObject dataSet = new JSONObject();
       dataSet.put("Email", account.getEmail());
       dataSet.put("Username", account.getUsername());
       response.getWriter().print(dataSet.toString());

       response.getWriter().flush();
   }
   ```

Please take a look [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#exchanging-api-keys-for-oauth-20-tokens) for more information

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi mario, thanks for the comprehensive reply. the thing is, I am currently working on a simple web application mosly intended for study purposes, and thus I'm currently not looking for paid solutions.